# How to map two classes to one table in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

```
public class User
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}
```

Can I map to a single table that looks like this?

```
| Id | SomeInfo | AccountName |
-------------------------------
| 1  | info1    | name1       |
| 2  | info2    | NULL        |
```

And after the mapping, 1 would map to:

```
User.SomeInfo        is "info1"
User.Account         is not null
User.Account.Name    is "name1"
```

and loading 2 would result in

```
User.SomeInfo        is "info2"
User.Account         is null
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You seem to be asking about [**Owned types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/). Or **Table splitting** from the same link.

Comment: I feel like thats a step closer but it still uses a One to One relationship. I want to be able to say, if the AccountName == null, then don't generate an Account object

Answer (score 0):

What you want cannot be done exactly the way you want - when using table splitting/owned entities that reside in the same table as the owner, it looks like EFCore requires the related entity not be null.

I figure there are two options - shared primary key (which would required two tables and an eager/explicit load to load the dependent entity with the principal) or Table-per-Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance (which would require two entity types).

Shared Primary Key:

```
public class SharedKeyPrincipal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PrincipalProperty { get; set; }
    public SharedKeyDependent Dependent { get; set; }
}
public class SharedKeyDependent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DependentProperty { get; set; }
    public SharedKeyPrincipal Principal { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<SharedKeyDependent>()
    .HasOne( d => d.Principal )
    .WithOne( p => p.Dependent )
    .IsRequired()
    .HasForeignKey<SharedKeyDependent>( d => d.Id );

var principals = dbContext.Set<SharedKeyPrincipal>()
    .Include( p => p.Dependent )
    .ToArray();
```

TPH:

```
public class InheritanceBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BaseEntityProperty { get; set; }
}
public class InheritanceDerivedEntity : InheritanceBaseEntity
{
    public int DerivedEntityProperty { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<InheritanceBaseEntity> InheritanceBaseEntities { get; set; }
public DbSet<InheritanceDerivedEntity> InheritanceDerivedEntities { get; set; }

// use .OfType<InheritanceDerivedEntity>() to get entities that have a 
//     non-null 'value' for the related properties
var inheritanceEntities = dbContext.Set<InheritanceBaseEntity>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  With the first example, it sets a one-to-one relationship, where i'm looking to have the account as null.  I can't seem to set optional one to one relationship in EF Core :(

Comment: `SharedKeyDependent` would be `Account` in this scenario and is nullable